# how to download invoice html to pdf using php code and without use of any library

Tags: php

I want to print a invoice page into pdf. But i do not want to use any such a library like a dompdf and any library.This is a client work in project to invoice mail in pdf format.
Please help me.

Comment: No library (another name for code)? So no code so um?

Comment: Any code that can help in download html to pdf file like a while html to word file dowload                                                                                                          <?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=example.doc");
    echo "<html>";
   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;      charset=Windows-1252\">";
   echo "<body>"; 
   ?>

Comment: Setting a header does not change the content of the file

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I suggest you to take a look at jspdf library. Well maintained by MrRio.

> https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: can you please give me whole code to implement or step wise guide to use jspdf library @Rooshan Akthar

Comment: @kishnamohandubey,
download the zip and include it. 
you can find more info here : http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/